# Elasticsearch: How to filter results with a specific word in a value using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to add a parameter to my search that filters results containing a specific word in a value. The query is searching for user history records and contains a `url` key. I need to filter out `/history` and any other url containing that string.

Here's my current query:

```
GET /user_log/_search 
{
  "size" : 50,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "user_id": 56678
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example of a record, boiled down to just the value we're looking at:

```
"_source": {
  "url": "/history?page=2&direction=desc",
},
```

How can the parameters of the search be changed to filter out this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **filter param** of [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in Elasticsearch.
if your url field is of type keyword, you can use the below query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {
                    "user_id": 56678
                }
            },
            "filter": { --> note filter 
                "term": {
                    "url": "/history"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sort of works, but still doesn't filter out values containing other iterations of the history page. For example, `/history?page=2&direction=desc` would still pass the filter. Is there a way to indiscriminately filter out any value that contains `history`?

Comment: @AustinPoulson can you provide your index mapping ? is this `url` field is text or keyword ?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I got it working with a slight variation. I'm using a different key to filter. Check out my answer to see the difference

Comment: @AustinPoulson as previously asked, can you provide your index mapping and some sample documents and expected results

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my specific issue. Instead of filtering on the url I'm filtering on a different value. Here's what I'm using now:

```
{
  "size" : 50,
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "user_id" : 56678 }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "match" : { "controller": "History" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still going to leave this question open for a while to see if anyone has other ways of solving the original problem.

Comment: Its been long time, I guess if you want you can accept one of the answer.

Comment: Yours is probably the more appropriate answer. Accepted :)